# VBA: Does IsEmpty require comparision to boolean value?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm confus. Which two forms are correct?

```
If IsEmpty(Cells(i, j)) Then
MsgBox ("This cell is empty!")
End If

If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, j)) Then
MsgBox ("This cell contains something!")
End If
```

...or:

```
If IsEmpty(Cells(i, j)) = True Then
MsgBox ("This cell is empty!")
End If

If IsEmpty(Cells(i, j)) = False Then
MsgBox ("This cell contains something!")
End If
```

Basically, do I need to compare the IsEmpty function to a boolean value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IsEmpty` function returns a boolean value, so your first examples are fine. Plus, I find them easier/simpler to read.

Comment: Well, I guess that answers it. I was mostly uncertain about the `If Not IsEmpty` part.

Comment: I find `If Not IsEmpty` much easier to think about than `If IsEmpty() = False`

Comment: The first is preferred as it is cleaner code (and demonstrates that you know what IsEmpty actually returns!). Just remember that if used mathematically any VBA boolean is 0 for False and -1 for True while a worksheet is 0 for FALSE and 1 for TRUE.

Answer (score 1):

Normally both should work.
Have you tried them?

Comment: I remember using both on different occasions, I just wanted to find out if there's something wrong with my thinking, or (by some magic) one of those methods is not as reliable as the other.

Comment: I guess they are both as reliable. I mean, I can't see how one of them could fail...

Comment: The both are accepted syntax. If IsEmpty(Cells(i, j)) Then Is probably a neater way to do things.